# How to combine elements from the list taking into account index of the list?

Tags: java, list

I have an array of lists

`List<String>[] tab = new ArrayList[5]`

Let say my tab lists look like:

```
tab[0]={1242}
tab[1]={London, Paris}
tab[2]={England, France}
tab[3]={Finance} 
tab[4]={No}
```

Now I need to make lines from above like

```
1242 London England Finance No
1242 Paris  France  Finance No
```

That means that if I have more than 1 element in particular lists then I need to take those elements using indexes - first with first, second with second and join them with the others. In addition I don't know in advance in which tab[?] I will get multiple elements.
Can anyone help me and show how to do this?

Comment: this is the most smelly-code-declaration ever: ***List<String>[] tab = new ArrayList[5]***

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works.  Questions of the form _"I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code"_ are considered off-topic.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ so help me and correct me if Im wrong, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. You can iterate through the array starting from index 1. Then inside the first loop have a second loop. There you concatenate the strings from the lists and if list has only one element then just concatenate it.

```
    List<String>[] tab = new ArrayList[5];
    tab[0] =  new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("1242"));
    tab[1] =  new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("London", "Paris"));
    tab[2] =  new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("England", "France"));
    tab[3] =  new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Finance"));
    tab[4] =  new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("No"));

    StringBuffer buffer;

    for(int j=1; j<=2; j++){
        buffer = new StringBuffer(tab[0].get(0)).append(" ");
        for(int i = 1; i < tab.length; i++){

          List<String> list = tab[i];

          if(list.size() == 1){
             buffer.append(list.get(0)).append(" ");
          }else{
             buffer.append(list.get(j - 1)).append(" ");
          }



        }
        System.out.println(buffer.toString());
    }
```